# Is there a sort of "OnLoaded" event in ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I have an entity containing a custom IList that relies on its max-capacity setting (it has a default max-capacity of 10).

The entity has a property containing the max-capacity for this particular instance.

When the entity is loaded (e.g. using GetById) the list is created with the default max-capacity.

Is there a way to get a specific method called by OrmLite when it has loaded/hydrated the instance?

```
public class Entity()
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public MyList<string> List { get; set; }

    public void Init(int maxlength)
    {
        this.MaxLength = maxlength;
        this.List = new MyList(maxlength);
    }
}


var aaa = new Entity();
aaa.Init(50);

// ...adds 5 items...

db.Save<Entity>(aaa);

var bbb = db.GetById<Entity>(1);

// aaa.MaxLength => 50
// aaa.List.MaxLength => 50
// bbb.MaxLength => 50
// bbb.List.MaxLength => 10
```